# Nestjs throw exception from empty result in the controller

Tags: exception, promise, nestjs

I have a control that calls a service.
If the service returns an empty payload from the db I want to throw an exception.

at the moment I am doing that in the service:
this is the service I have at the moment with the exception.

```
async getPreferences(eUserId: string): Promise<UserPreferences> {

    const userPreferences = await this.userPreferencesModel.findOne({
      eUserId,
    });

    if (!userPreferences) {
      throw new NotFoundException("We couldn't find your user preferences");
    }

    return userPreferences;
  }
```

I want the controller to handle the exception, The issue is that the controller response is a Promise.
How can I handle that?

This is what I shave done:

```
@Get()
  async getPreferences(
    @Headers('x-e-user-id') eUserId: string,
  ): Promise<UserPreferences> {
  
    const userPreferences = this.userPreferencesService.getPreferences(eUserId);

    console.log('userPreferences: ', userPreferences);
    // Here is what I am trying to monitor...
    if (userPreferences) {
      throw new NotFoundException("We couldn't find your user preferences");
    }

    return userPreferences;
  }
```

Ther console.log in the controller returns:

```
userPreferences:  Promise { <pending> }
```

Now, if the service response is empty no exception is thrown.

How can I monitor the service result in order to throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways you can solve this. Here's one.

Don't throw an error in your service, just return the result or `null`.

```
async getPreferences(eUserId: string): Promise<UserPreferences | null> {
  return this.userPreferencesModel.findOne({
    eUserId,
  });
}
```

Then in your controller `await` for the result, you forgot this.  That's why you are seeing a pending promise. After the result has been resolved, check if any user preferences were returned and throw the `NotFoundException` if not.

```
@Get()
async getPreferences(@Headers('x-e-user-id') eUserId: string): Promise<UserPreferences> {
  const userPreferences = await this.userPreferencesService.getPreferences(eUserId);
  if (!userPreferences) {
    throw new NotFoundException("We couldn't find your user preferences");
  }

  return userPreferences;
}
```

I would not throw `NotFoundException` or any other HTTP related error from your service. Leave that responsibility up to your controller, don't tie your service (logic) to HTTP error codes. Throw errors here that are not aware of the context (HTTP) they are being used in.

PS: You might also consider passing the user ID via the query string or as a route parameter instead of via the headers.

Comment: Thanks, adding the `await` solved the issue. How do you suggest handling the errors so they won't be aware of the status code?
As well, the user id should not be seen, do think it is better to pass as a  route param?

Comment: You could just throw standard errors or your own custom ones and write an exception filter in NestJS to catch and translate them. As for the user ID I prefer it as a route parameter, it results in a more human readable URL. Even if you put it in the header it is still visible for anybody that knows how to inspect the network traffic.